# How to change the default font of the Chrome PDF viewer

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, chrome

The Chrome PDF viewer defaults to a font with terrible kerning. I am using Arch Linux, how can I fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Chrome and would be better answered on SuperUser.

Comment: I think (still) that browser fonts are connected to OSs. My experience confirms this (ex. Debian vs. Ubuntu). I can't vote, but would vote against closing.

Comment: @dr01 Chrome runs under Linux, so this question is on-topic here. Sure, Chrome runs under Windows. So does bash. That doesn't make them off-topic here.